# Oracle - SELECT-INSERT locking pattern

Tags: oracle, concurrency, plsql

I have a table `Orders` (with columns `orderId`, `orderType`, `userId`, `state`, ...). I need my process to do the following:

1. Check if there exist an order with specific type, with specific state for specific user (SELECT).
2. If such an order doesn't exist - create one (INSERT).

So basically I want to assure that there is always only one order with:

- orderType = x
- userId = y
- state = z

I can't however create constraints because there can exist more than one order for x1, y1, z1.

I must say that I'm not experienced in Oracle. I've read [this article](http://broadh2o.net/docs/database/oracle/oracleLocks.html) on locks in Oracle and it seams that the only lock type which would be useful here is:

```
LOCK TABLE Orders IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

But I think it is overkill to lock whole table only for some subset of data. I tried `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE OF <update_column>` using different columns for `<update_column>` but they allowed me to insert new rows.

Is there any pattern for this type of concurrency? It seams that Oracle created `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE OF ...` for the SELECT-UPDATE pattern. Is there anything similar for SELECT-INSERT?

Comment: If you have a unique index on the appropriate columns, skip the SELECT and just perform the INSERT.  If the row already exists, the INSERT will fail and you can catch the duplicate-index exception.

Comment: @DwB, this is the main issue. I've written above that I can't have constraints. For example I can have many orders with the same type for the same user which have state = "Done". But I can have only one in state "Draft".

Comment: What about creating 2 tables.  one for drafts (that uses a primary key or a unique index) and one for not-drafts.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a unique function-based index to enforce this sort of constraint.  If you want to enforce that there is a unique row with a `state` of "Done" but allow many rows with a `state` of "Draft".

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_index_name
    ON( CASE WHEN state = 'Done' THEN orderType ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN state = 'Done' THEN userId ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN state = 'Done' THEN state ELSE NULL END );
```

Comment: Hi Justin. The problem is that I can't set the constraint. The table is used by other systems which have different business rules. So there are some types of order which doesn't have this constraint.

Comment: @LukaszLysik - So you're saying that some systems are allowed to have multiple "Done" orders with the same `orderType` and `userId` but others aren't?  And there are no other columns in the table that identify whether the order is from a system that allows duplicates or not?  That seems like a rather poor data model.  Is there any way to identify programmatically which rows are subject to the rule and which are not?

Comment: Yes, there is some subset of orderTypes. This is configurable in some other table.